# The XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I recently updated my Visual Studio to 15.6.0 version and i install 27 API level android SDK.
but when i install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm` nuget package received this build error

> The "XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs" task failed
>   unexpectedly.System.IO.InvalidDataException: End of Central Directory
>   record could not be found.   at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.ReadEndOfCentralDirectory()   at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive.Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen)   at
>   System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive..ctor(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode
>   mode, Boolean leaveOpen, Encoding entryNameEncoding)   at
>   Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarProguardConfigs.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

This error related to `Xamarin.Build.Download` package. This package is depending on `the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` package.

I restart VS and my computer many times, and reinstall packages but anything not resolve my problem.

Can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved by updating `.net framework` and `android support repository` and install 57 beta version of the package. This is not latest version of the package compatible with android 8!